# I want to return the cell value using the IF formula but giving me logical return

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to return if its "NO" should return value of Mismatch and if the cell has number in it it should return "Duplicate and the number itself. But it is returning me the logical value.
I am using this formula `=IF(F4="NO","Mismatch",IF(F4=ISNUMBER(F4),"Duplicate"&F4))`

Would really appreciate if you could guide me on this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzIQc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ISNUMBER" returns True or False, you don't want to test if F4 = that result as that will always be untrue unless F4 actually contains a logical "FALSE" value. Also, your second IF function does not define what to display if F4 is neither No nor a number. Blank perhaps? Try

```
=IF(F4="NO","Mismatch",IF(ISNUMBER(F4),"Duplicate "&F4,""))
```

(note the space after "Duplicate" for improved appearance).